# How do I create a deep copy of a mobx class with observables and computeds?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I want to create a deep copy of an object that has mobx observable and computed properties.

The goal is to create copy item for local editing, that can be committed or discarded.

I've found an example of this behavior but it is from mobx-state-tree:

[image]

How can I achieve the same behaviour in mobx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**createViewModel**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#createviewmodel) from the `mobx-utils` package.

**Example**

```
class Todo {
  @observable firstName = "Foo";
  @observable lastName = "Bar";
  @computed get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

const todo = new Todo();
const todoCopy = createViewModel(todo);

todoCopy.firstName = "Baz";

// ...

// Submit the changes to the original todo
todoCopy.submit();
```

Comment: OP asked for a "deep copy". `createViewModel` creates a *shallow* pseudo-copy (change-tracking wrapper)